# Access violation on `jmp` to appended segment

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, exe, ida

So I've used CFF Explorer to add a code section to an `.exe` file. I've set the section characteristics to `0x60000020` (executable, readable, contains code) and created some dummy code there using IDA.

However, when I injected a `jmp` to that code from the original `.text` segment, all I got was an access violation. I used IDA to patch the binary, so it generated offsets for me, but it seems to be right:

```
jmp     far ptr 6:75D100h
```

The resulting opcode looks right too:

```
EA 00 D1 75 00 06 00
```

But as soon as I hit that jump - "The instruction referenced memory at 0xFFFFFFFF, memory can't be read". I've experimented a bit with offsets to no avail; The appended segment seems to be properly loaded in memory.

Would be grateful for any hint to what I am missing here:)

Comment: What makes you think `6` is a correct segment selector?

Comment: @Jester as the matter of fact, it's not - looks like the correct one is 5 - but the segfault persists.
I have no idea why IDA puts 6 there, thank you

Comment: `5` looks very suspicious too. `7` could work if you allocated a new descriptor in the LDT.

Comment: @Jester I guess I'll have to figure out how to do that:D

Comment: Better question is, why do you need a new selector? Why do you need a far jump?

Comment: @Jester well I may indeed be having an XY problem here, far jump is what IDA generated from my "jmp 75D100h". Am I ok with a regular jump then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129648/discussion-between-jester-and-ap31).

Comment: Entering `jmp near ptr 75d100h` should get IDA to use the correct near jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this as answered - the solution, as proposed by @Jester and @RossRidge, was to drop the `jmp far`. Using

```
jmp     near ptr 75D100h
```

fixed everything. Have to say IDA's behavior can be somewhat wierd.